# Use browser history admin-on-rest

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

can we use browser history in admin-on-rest (React JS) instead on hashhistory?
do i need change something in admin-on-rest or just set the server to handle the URL ?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently now it's only a matter of creating an instance of browser history from the `history` package and passing it to the `<Admin />` component:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

const history = createHistory();

const App = () => (
    <Admin history={history}>
        ...
    </Admin>
);
```

As per [documentation](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/docs/Admin.md#history)

Comment: I did this, but I don't see 'history' propagating to the child props. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you need to write a custom app instead of using the `<Admin>` component. It's documented in [the official documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/CustomApp.html).